# Why is egit with LFS showing "The system cannot find the file"?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, git-lfs

Using Eclipse with egit. Recently added LFS. Any push to remote gives an error.

As a simple test case: I cloned a remote repository, then, without changing any files, pushed to a new branch on remote, and got this:

```
Can't connect to any URI... (Rejected by "pre-push" hook. 
open d:\dev\workspace\src\com\freightos\TestExcel.xlsx:
The system cannot find  the file specified.
```

Note that:

- In the command line, pushing works
- egit *is* invoking LFS. I know this because LFS pulled some large files, but also because uninstalling LFS produces a different error message.
- The mentioned large file is indeed not present in this branch. It did exist in other branches, which were not  involved in the above git workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running `git lfs fetch --all`, the problem is resolved. It fetches the old files not in the present branch.

```
$ git lfs fetch --all
Scanning for all objects ever referenced...
* 740 objects found
Fetching objects...
Git LFS: (498 of 498 files) 2.07 GB / 2.01 GB
```